# CSS/JS file paths and .htaccess with virtual host

Tags: .htaccess, path, server

I have a test website on a server using a Tilde URL.

The site works, but CSS and other assets files are being called incorrectly as below.

The site is on a URL similar:  92.111.222.333/~tilde/

In my HTML I call the assets files like:

```
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the path being called by the page is:

```
92.111.222.333/assets/css/style.css
```

rather than

```
92.111.222.333/~tilde/assets/css/style.css
```

Is there an easy fix for this?  Can this be done using .htaccess?  I know i can just add the actual URL to the CSS/assets file path, but i have 2 development environments that would disturb this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+~
RewriteRule ^(assets/.*)$ ~tilde/$0 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This doesn't seem to work.  Any path for assets files is removing the /~tilde.  So i need a solution to always add that into any URL path being called.

Comment: I don't understand **Any path for assets files is removing the /~tilde**. This is tested rule and works fine on my Apache.

Comment: Yes. It is still calling 92.111.222.333/assets/css/style.css, rather than 92.111.222.333/~tilde/assets/css/style.css

Comment: That means you didn't place this rule in .htaccess under site root. site root may be different from `~tilde/.htaccess`. Check your local Apache config

Comment: It's in the /public_html folder.  I am making changes to other variables in the .htaccess and they are working - just not this one

Comment: Does this rule redirect to `/foo`. `RewriteRule ^assets/.* /foo [L,R]` ?

Comment: No it doesn't do anything.  Again, thanks for your help on this

Comment: Well that explains that rule is not in right .htaccess. This rule can only work from site that handles `http://example.com/assets/..` requests. I'm not server admin but you may need to add a VirtualHost for this.